# How can I add a Facebook pixel to a site hosted in Sitecore?

Tags: analytics, facebook, cms, tracking-pixel

My customer has numerous business locations hosted in Sitecore, and I need to add the pixel code to each. I have found the area that allows for Google Analytics, but can't find anything relating to adding a Facebook pixel.

Has anyone done this?